# How to keep the multiple selected value in dropdown using jstl tags?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

```
        //This is jsp code.........
        <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
        <html>  
        <head>  
        <title>Drop down</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#delete").click(function(){
                var d = [];
                $.each($("#delete option:selected"), function(){            
                   d.push($(this).val());
                });
                var s=(d.join(", "));
                console.log(s);
               $("#delete_empId").val(s);
               console.log($("#delete_empId").val());

            });
        });
        </script>
        </head>  
        <body>   

          <div align="center">
            <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultiple" modelAttribute="employee">  
            <table>  
            <tr>  
              <td>First Name :</td>  
              <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>  
             </tr>  
             <tr>  
              <td>Last Name :</td>  
              <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>  
             </tr> 
             <tr>  
              <td>emp_Id :</td>  
              <td><form:input path="emp_Id" /></td>  
             </tr> 
             <tr>
              <td>email_Id :</td>
              <td><form:input path="email_ID"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>phone_No :</td>
              <td><form:input path="phone_No"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>City :</td>
              <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>  
              <td> </td>  
              <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>   
             </tr>  
            </table>  
          <input type= "hidden" id="delete_empId" name="delete_empId"   />

             </form:form>
        </div>
          <div  align="center">  
          <h2 style="color:blue">SelectBox:</h2>
           <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultipleEmpDetails">  
            <select id="delete"  multiple name="employees"> 
            <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee"> 
             <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" >${employee.firstName}</option>
             ${msg}
            </c:forEach>
            </select> 
             <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
            </form:form>
          </div>  
           <div>
                 <h4 style="color:red">${message}</h4>  
            </div>

        </body>  
        </html>
```

How to keep the value as selected using jstl tags, without using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To keep multiple selected value, we need to add `selected` attribute to the respective `<option>` tag.

I am thinking that, you want to add `selected` attribute based on some condition, for I am using `<c:choose>` tag.

Try the following code:

```
<select id="delete"  multiple name="employees"> 
   <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee"> 
     <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${some condition that satisfies your requirement }">
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" selected="selected"> ${employee.firstName} </option>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" >${employee.firstName}</option>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: <select  id="delete"  multiple name="employees">      
    <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee"> 
       <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${employee.emp_Id==delete_emp_Id }">
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" selected="selected"> ${employee.firstName} </option>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" >${employee.firstName}</option>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
     ${msg}
    </c:forEach>
    </select>

Comment: i have written like this but noo action is performimg

Comment: 1. Where you are getting problem? 
2. Is the options are loaded into the `select`? 
3. Why you are using `${msg}` inside of the `c:forEach`? 
4. From where you are getting the `delete_emp_Id` value?

Comment: i have canged the condition..when i clicking on search button both are getiing selected..

Comment: <c:when test="${delete!=selected}"> this is my condition

Comment: the value which i am searching and employee which is selected both are getting selected how can i solve.

Comment: Add your search code to your question and elaborate your question, what you have done, what output is coming and what you want

Comment: My question is when i press search button the employee which i am searching and the employee in the dropdown which i am selected but be displayed in dropdown but the value which i am selecting in dropdown must be highlighted and the other must be normal..Please give the solution fast

Comment: @RequestMapping("/search")
  public String searchEmp(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp,Model model) {
    List<Employee> empList = null; 
    empList=empService.searchEmpDetails(emp);
   
    Employee emp1=new Employee();
        if(empList!=null){
       model.addAttribute("empList", empList);
        if(empList.isEmpty()){
      model.addAttribute("message","This Employee Details are not present");
      }
        }
        model.addAttribute("employee", emp1);
         return "empList";
        }